# ¿Como puedo hacer para insertar un Tab adentro de un Drawer en ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Este es el tab Navigation

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import AccountScreen from "../screens/Account";
import SearchScreen from "../screens/Search";
import FavoritesScreen from "../screens/Favorites";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function NavigationTab() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Mi cuenta" component={AccountScreen}></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen name="Buscar" component={SearchScreen}></Tab.Screen>
      <Tab.Screen name="Favoritos" component={FavoritesScreen}></Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Este el el DrawerNavigation en donde quiero insertar mi tabnavigation

```
import React from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Account from "../screens/Account";
import NavigationTab from "./src/navigation/NavigationTab";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function NavigationDrewer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Accout" component={Account}>
        <NavigationTab></NavigationTab>
      </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
 }
```

Y este es el app.js en donde se ejecuta toda la navegacion, pero al final me marca error

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import NavigationTab from "./src/navigation/NavigationTab";
import NavigationDrewer from "./src/navigation/NavigationDrawer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <NavigationDrewer></NavigationDrewer>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Que parte del codigo estara mal para que funcione, porque por separado si me funciona, tanto el tab, como el drawer